# Why a Taipy app is very slow after deployment?

Tags: websocket, deployment, gunicorn, uwsgi, taipy

I have made, as an amateur, an application that uses Taipy. The application works normally through the python interpreter on localhost.

I have followed the instructions to use as application server [gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) and [uwsgi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) with nginx as a reverse proxy to make server my computer. The application works normally but to display the first page it takes a long time, maybe more than 5 minutes.

The network in the browser sometimes shows ns error websocket connection refused, as can be seen in the photo.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVyJW.jpg)

In the nginx logs i found the following:
[crit] 744#744: *1 connect() to unix:/home/fapp/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream.
But the file myproject.sock is in the path it goes to find it.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide all the information on your setup? OS? Browser? Python version? Packages installed? Which tutorial did you follow?